# How to deal with the current data in test methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

In my example, I've got two methods for Enabling and Disabling and account and I'm gonna to write a test method for each one.

The problem is that I've got to consider the original status for the data and restore it after testing it, even in a sample database, to keep the data consisted for the next test.

```
public void DisableAndEnableAccount()
{
    var client = new GwIntegrationServiceSoapClient();

    string userName = "admin";
    Account account = client.GetAccountByUsername(userName);
    int accountID = account.Id;

    bool isActiveOrginalValue = account.IsActive;

    if (isActiveOrginalValue)
    {
        client.DisableAccount(accountID);
        account = client.GetAccountByUsername(userName);

        Assert.IsFalse(account.IsActive);

        client.EnableAccount(accountID);
        account = client.GetAccountByUsername(userName);

        Assert.IsTrue(account.IsActive);
    }
    else
    {
        client.EnableAccount(accountID);
        account = client.GetAccountByUsername(userName);

        Assert.IsTrue(account.IsActive);

        client.DisableAccount(accountID);
        account = client.GetAccountByUsername(userName);

        Assert.IsFalse(account.IsActive);
    }
}
```

I think that my test method isn't written in a good way, Any idea how to deal with such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use test data (test user accounts) in your tests, not real ones. (In fact, it is strongly recommended to use a separate test DB for your tests, never the real live production DB.) Then you are free to set it up any way you need prior to the test. Btw it is recommended to do the setup in the separate `setUp()` method (or one annotated with `@Before` in JUnit 4).

Note however, that "classic" unit tests should not depend on external entities like a DB or the file system: they should focus on testing one unit (class, method), isolated from the rest of the world. This is usually achieved by [*dependency injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [*mocking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), i.e. hiding them behind interfaces, so that in unit tests, you can supply a dummy implementation which e.g. doesn't connect to the DB, just verifies the calls made to it and the parameters passed.

Testing the whole integrated system is still useful, just it is not unit, rather *integration testing*. Unit tests can be much finer grained, easier to understand and maintain, and faster, so whenever you can, it is best to start with unit tests, then once you are sure the smaller parts are working fine, put together some integration tests to verify that the system works end to end.

Comment: Actually I'm dealing with a web service, I preferred to deal with the live one (in the development house) to avoid update the database schema for each change on live one.

Comment: @French, sorry, now I couldn't grasp whether you are testing on the live DB or not???

Comment: It's a central db used in the office for the development

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Actually it's a web service and I wonder whether I can use DI and mocking with it.

Comment: @French, if you only test it from outside via SOAP, it is system / integration testing by definition so you can't use mocks and DI.

Answer (score 0):

You're always going to have trouble restoring the data to its original state using this method.  The solution, in general, is to avoid trying to do this, as @Péter Török points out (I also happen to agree almost completely with his post).

Many things could go wrong between the various steps in your test:  what if the internet connection is dropped, and you lose connection to the web service?  What happens if you make a mistake in your test code and break the test account's live data?

If absolutely have to have some kind of automated testing with an external web service, I would suggest coming to an arrangement with the owner of the service to be able to reset your test entities automatically, or something like that.  This way, you can focus on having your tests actually test functionality, not worry about how you will trick the data back to the way it was to start with.